# Avoid percentage strings (".5%") for lists with a single item

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to find the index for a given quantile for all lists in a list. However lists with a single item end up containing a percentage string (".5%") while lists with multiple items do not.

This causes problems when I want to access the list items later, because I expect them to be equally named. How can I make sure no list items contain the percentage string?

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 2, 2), b=c(2, 3, 4, 5))
tmp = aggregate(b ~ a, df, c)
sapply(tmp$b, function(x) which.min(abs(x - quantile(x, .05))))

1.5%    2 
   1    1
```

Comment: This is due to the way  R handles names in basic math operations (`+`, `-` etc.). Usually, the names are preserved if no recycling is needed. You can see it from `x<-setNames(5,"a");print(x+2);print(x+1:3)`. However here, you can maybe use `unname`: `sapply(tmp$b, function(x) unname(which.min(abs(x - quantile(x, .05)))))`.

Comment: @nicola: `unname` works. You may post this as a suggested answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using purrr function map_dbl, the .5% seems to disappear.
Click here to learn more about the map functions http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html

```
library(purrr)
df = data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 2, 2), b=c(2, 3, 4, 5))
tmp = aggregate(b ~ a, df, c)
map_dbl(tmp$b, function(x) which.min(abs(x - quantile(x, .05))))

1 2
1 1
```

Comment: Nice to know for later!